# Units for Screen.WorkingArea

Tags: winforms

Is the rectangle returned by `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.WorkingArea` in units of pixels or Device Independent Pixels (i.e. units of 1/96 inch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a single monitor is in use, the method calls `SystemInformation.WorkingArea`; if multiple monitors are in use, it calls `GetMonitorInfo()`.  Both return the number of pixels as virtual screen coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

It contains the width and height of your screen based on your screen resolution.

If I understood your question correctly, Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width.ToString());
```